Disable imePadding() in Material3 ModalBottomSheet for better IME Handling
I'm working with the ModalBottomSheet in Material3, and I ran into a limitation regarding how IME is handled. The Google Material3 ModalBottomSheet is structured like this:
fun ModalBottomSheet(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ...
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .imePadding() // IME padding applied here
    ) {
        ModalBottomSheetContent(modifier)
    }
...
}

The caller can modify the bottom sheet's content modifier and the window insets through the contentWindowInsets parameter but the imePadding() is still enforced and that makes it difficult to manage IME behavior as needed.
If there was a way to consumeWindowInsets beforehand it could work but ModalBottomSheet is a new view altogether so it's not like we can wrap it up in a composable ourselves.
There are ugly workarounds like declaring what should happen if the IME is visible or not but are there any other approaches to handle this?

Did you find a solution?

@MakinTosH What made my use case work was making the content of modal bottom sheet (above the IME) scrollable. I did not find a solution for the question but making the content scrollable makes it non-pushable by the IME.
